# How can I select the nearest value less-than and greater-than a given value efficiently?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables, one for values one for location and am trying to interpolate location.  The tables have been simplified to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE value(
    Timestamp DATETIME2,
    Value float NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Timestamp)
);

CREATE TABLE location(
    Timestamp DATETIME2,
    Position INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Timestamp)
); 

INSERT INTO value VALUES 
    ('2011/12/1 16:55:01', 1),
    ('2011/12/1 16:55:02', 5),
    ('2011/12/1 16:55:05', 10),
    ('2011/12/1 16:55:08', 6);

INSERT INTO location VALUES 
    ('2011/12/1 16:55:00', 0),
    ('2011/12/1 16:55:05', 10),
    ('2011/12/1 16:55:10', 5)
```

The expected results would be

```
TimeStamp, Value, LowerTime, LowerLocation, UpperTime, UpperLocation
2011-12-01 16:55:01,  1, 2011-12-01 16:55:00,  0, 2011-12-01 16:55:05, 10
2011-12-01 16:55:02,  5, 2011-12-01 16:55:00,  0, 2011-12-01 16:55:05, 10
2011-12-01 16:55:05, 10, 2011-12-01 16:55:05, 10, 2011-12-01 16:55:05, 10
2011-12-01 16:55:08,  6, 2011-12-01 16:55:05, 10, 2011-12-01 16:55:10,  5
```

(Keep in mind this is simplified sample data to get the idea of the query I am trying to perform across.)

To do the interpolation, I need to figure out the time and locations before and after a given values time.  I am currently doing this with a query that looks like:

```
SELECT 
    V.Timestamp, 
    V.Value, 
    (SELECT MAX(Timestamp) FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp <= V.Timestamp) as LowerTime,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Position FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp <= V.Timestamp ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as LowerLocation,
    (SELECT MIN(Timestamp) FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp >= V.Timestamp) as UpperTime,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Position FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp >= V.Timestamp ORDER BY timestamp ASC) as UpperLocation
 FROM 
    dbo.value V
```

Now this works, but this obviously is doing a lot of work.  I'm thinking there must be a query simplification that I'm missing but I've been playing with it all morning and haven't come up with anything concrete.  Hoping someone here has a better idea.

I am currently exploring if there is a way to figure out the LowerTime and UpperTime and use those in determining the Locations.  Something like:

```
SELECT 
    V.Timestamp, 
    V.Value, 
    (SELECT MAX(Timestamp) FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp <= V.Timestamp) as LowerTime,
    (SELECT Position FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp = LowerTime) as LowerLocation,
    (SELECT MIN(Timestamp) FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp >= V.Timestamp) as UpperTime,
    (SELECT Position FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp = UpperTime) as UpperLocation
 FROM 
    dbo.value V
```

but this doesn't work.

EDIT1: Updated query as suggested.  However no visible change in execution time.

EDIT2: Added my thoughts of the approach I am currently trying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For simplicity you may at least use `MAX()` and `MIN()` functions for querying `timestamp` field instead of `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`.

Full query will be

```
SELECT 
    V.Timestamp, 
    V.Value, 
    (SELECT MAX(Timestamp) FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp <= V.Timestamp) as LowerTime,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Position FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp <= V.Timestamp ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as LowerLocation,
    (SELECT MIN(Timestamp) FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp >= V.Timestamp) as UpperTime,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Position FROM dbo.location WHERE Timestamp >= V.Timestamp ORDER BY timestamp ASC) as UpperLocation
 FROM 
    dbo.value V
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  That's a good point - I will try that.  I am hoping to somehow reduce or get rid of those 4 queries though.

Comment: Thanks.  I've marked your answer as the answer as it was the best of the options given.  This did help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick (although I think the join looks quite ugly):

```
;with OrderedLocations as (
    select
        v.Timestamp,
        v.Value,
        l.Timestamp as tsl,
        l.Position,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.Timestamp ORDER BY CASE WHEN l.Timestamp <= v.Timestamp THEN l.Timestamp ELSE '00010101' END desc) as PrevRN,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.Timestamp ORDER BY CASE WHEN l.Timestamp >= v.Timestamp THEN l.Timestamp ELSE '99991231' END asc) as NextRN
    from
        value v
            cross join
        location l
)
select
    ol1.Timestamp,
    ol1.Value,
    ol1.tsl,
    ol1.Position,
    ol2.tsl,
    ol2.Position
from
    OrderedLocations ol1
        inner join
    OrderedLocations ol2
        on
            ol1.Timestamp = ol2.Timestamp and
            ol1.Value = ol2.Value
where
    ol1.PrevRN = 1 and
    ol2.NextRN = 1
```

Unfortunately, as with most efficiency/performance questions, the answer tends to be try lots of different combinations with your *actual* tables and data, and measure how each one performs.

---

An alternative (avoiding the join) using the same CTE as above would be:

```
SELECT Timestamp,Value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PrevRN=1 THEN tsl END),MAX(CASE WHEN PrevRN=1 then Position END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN NextRN=1 THEN tsl END),MAX(CASE WHEN NextRN=1 then Position END)
FROM
    OrderedLocations
where PrevRN=1 or NextRN=1
group by Timestamp,Value
```

---

The CTE (`OrderedLocations`) is trying to construct a rowset where every row from location is matched to every row in `value`. For each resulting row, we calculate two `ROW_NUMBER`s - the row number where we number all rows with a lower or equal timestamp (`PrevRN`) in descending order, and another where we number all rows with a greater or equal timestamp (`NextRN`) ascending. We then construct our final result by just considering those rows where one of those row numbers is 1.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I don't know what this is doing exactly.  Running it on a simple set of data yielded no results.  I will study your answer and see if helps.

Comment: @brianestey - well, if you have some sample data and expected results, please add them to your question - it's a lot easier for us to write working queries if we're able to test them ourselves before posting them as answers.

Comment: good idea, I've updated the question again with some data points I am using for testing and also the expected output I am looking for.

Comment: @brianestey - I've now partitioned by `v.Timestamp` in my CTE, and get the expected results you've posted. (I'd initially tested with only a single row in the `value` table, oops)

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I've tested this and it does give the expected results but I am having some performance issues with this.  For example, I inserted 5000 rows into the value table, 1250 rows into the location table and the original query completes in 0~1 second, but this query takes minutes with the same data (~5.5 minutes).  Does that sound reasonable to you?